# Wordpress customized single post page and comments

Tags: wordpress, customization

How do I 'reroute' a 'Questions' category post page to a new/customized single.php and comments.php page (I'm renaming it singlequestion.php/singlequestioncomments.php after editing)

Usage:

I'm adding the Question and Answer Forum plugin and need to customize a couple of things.

From the home page, the user can click on the 'QA' link which takes them to a 'page' that has the QA form. From there, they post their question and I go in and approve it as a post, tag it as 'question' category, publish it and respond in the comments section as the 'answer'.

I also need to change the words 'comments' and submit 'comment' to read: Answers/Submit Answer on the post page w/ the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate your existing single.php template file, call it single-post.php. Make a file for your questions category, called single-question.php

In single.php you do the logic to see if the current post is within your category. Like below:

```
<?php
if ( in_category('X') ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-question.php');
} else {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-post.php');
}
?>
```

You need to change X in in_category('X') to be the numerical ID of your questions category.